# How to write Shell Namespace extension for Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, shell

I want to add a folder to Windows explorer under Tree View just like Dropbox, Skydrive and Google Drive. I have found that it can be done by using Shell Namespace Extension which will be built using C++ and avoid using .NET.

I was reading Microsoft articles for building such extensions:

[Understanding Shell Namespace Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095.aspx)

But I cannot understand how should I start building it in Visual Studio and what should be the first step. I was also not able to find any helpful tutorials to get started. I am on Windows 10 and using Visual Studio 2015.

Please guide me to easy to understand article that can help me get Started. Thanks

Comment: Read the next section https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067(v=vs.85).aspx. You need to write a COM DLL and implement some specific interfaces and register it.